# ubuntu subsystem windows 10 cannot run sql after change datadir

Tags: mysql, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I need to change my datadir. Here is the manipulation I made:

editing the my.cnf :

```
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql   ->  datadir = /mnt/d/mysql
```

copying mysql data to the new folder:

```
cp -pr /var/lib/mysql/* /mnt/d/mysql
```

editing apparmor:

```
/var/lib/mysql/ -> /mnt/d/mysql/,
```

restarting the services :

```
service mysql restart
```

But when I restore to the dump database I get an error:

```
ERROR 27 (HY000) at line 25: Can't sync file './test/' to disk (Errcode: 5 - Input/output error)
```

Any idea?